# Display alert dialog box based on Maps place Click?

Tags: android, listview, maps, android-alertdialog

I am practicing the Android maps now i am getting the maps successfully in my emulator when i search in the Google market i found one  Interesting App i am try for to develop the example app is

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=streetdirectory.mobile&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInN0cmVldGRpcmVjdG9yeS5tb2JpbGUiXQ..

```
package com.example.tutorials;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;  
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class GoogleMap extends MapActivity  
{

     MapView mapView; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
    {
    return false;
    }

    public void changeMap(String area)
    {

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    MapController mc=mapView.getController();


    GeoPoint myLocation=null;

    double lat = 0;
    double lng = 0;
    try
    {

    Geocoder g = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    java.util.List<android.location.Address> result=g.getFromLocationName(area, 1);
    if(result.size()>0){

    Toast.makeText(GoogleMap.this, "country: " + String.valueOf(result.get(0).getCountryName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    lat = result.get(0).getLatitude();
    lng = result.get(0).getLongitude();

    }            
    else{
    Toast.makeText(GoogleMap.this, "record not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
    }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
    Toast.makeText(GoogleMap.this, "Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    myLocation = new GeoPoint(
    (int) (lat * 1E6),
    (int) (lng * 1E6));
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    mc.animateTo(myLocation);
    mc.setZoom(10);
    mapView.invalidate();
    }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btnSearch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        EditText txtSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMapSearch);
        String area=txtSearch.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(GoogleMap.this, "Click-" + String.valueOf(area), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GoogleMap.this.changeMap(area);


                    }
        });

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(14);

        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom); 

        }

    }
```

by this code i am getting search place in Android maps.how can i provide dialog box .when we click on the maps place?

Thanks in Advance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MapViewer extends MapActivity {

MapView mapView;

MapController mapController;

GeoPoint mgeoPoint;

Drawable marker;

MyLocationOverlay mLocationOverlay;

MotionEvent e;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    mapController = mapView.getController();

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapView.setStreetView(true);


    marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(), marker
            .getIntrinsicHeight());

    mapView.getOverlays().add(new MapOverlay(marker));


    mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(mLocationOverlay);

    setViewLocation();
}


@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Hello").setIcon(
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher).setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog , int which) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }).setCancelable(true).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog , int which) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    })

            .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dismiss",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }).create();


        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
        }


private void setViewLocation() {



    String[] coordinates = { "22.716221", "75.896816" };

    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
    mgeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mapController.animateTo(mgeoPoint);
    mapController.setZoom(15);

    mapView.invalidate();

}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


Point scrPoint;


private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat , double lon) {

    return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lon * 1E6)));
}


class MapOverlay extends
        com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    List<OverlayItem> ListofGeopoints = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();


    public MapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker ) {

        super(defaultMarker);

        ListofGeopoints.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(22.716221, 75.896816),
                "IN", "India"));

        populate();

    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {

    switch (index) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GeoLocation : 0",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                showDialog(0);
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }


    String add = "";

    List<Address> add_List = new ArrayList<Address>();


    private void getAddress() {

        add_List = ReverseGeocode
                .getFromLocation(35.594227, -105.223618, 2);

    }


    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (ListofGeopoints.get(i));
    }


    @Override
    public int size() {
        return ListofGeopoints.size();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur help when i click on the place market the alert dailog is getting how can i capture the place to alert and display in List?

Comment: You want to show complete address of the place?? For that you have to perform reverse geocoding search on web for that and post the problem if any. Upvote and accept the post if useful

Comment: i want show that place in  Android List view based on dialog box reslut?

Comment: It's so easy put some your efforts and if you face any problem post on the site

Comment: i have small dout how can i search place dynamically and i want show in the map?

Comment: here we are using harcoding values ?

Comment: Try the following.

Write a class which derives from the Overlay class and override the onTap() method. Then you can add your overlay to the your MapView. A GeoPoint object, which represents the position of you tap, is passed to the onTap() method when you tab somewhere on the map.

Comment: i mean i want provide search option. to search places in The map once place is find we can click that mark dialog box is carrying the place and add it to the list-view that is what i want prepare?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [popup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for this .Popup can be displayed any where on screen .just note the c0ordinates of click and display popup on that place.

Below are general example for the same.

Create a *layout* for your popup

```
private PopupWindow mPopup;
//Some code here
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //Inflate the view from a predefined XML layout
    //This is how your popup will look like
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));

    mPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, "width", "height", true);
    //Use below when you want to display at specific x-y coord on screen
    mPopup .showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, "x-coord", "y-coord");


    //You can use some thing like below to get views from your layout
    TextView mText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id."id for textview");
    mText.setText("Just an example you can set buttons and listviews in similar fashion");

    mPopup.dismiss();//When you want to dismiss Popup
```

You want to have listView so your layout xml will have a listview. use adapter to fill the listview same way as you do normally.

Comment: just now i edited my code by that i am getting the search place in maps how can i give popup and display in list view of that marked place click ?

Comment: @User you can refine or update  your question I will give you answer accordingly,you dont need to edit my answer.

Comment: i updated my code please see once and tel me how can i add popup for that map search place click?